# How to label a series of sums until they turn positive again?

Tags: python, pandas

what is the most efficient approach to this problem? I have a df with users (users are not unique), a month column and a profit/loss column. I want to create a new binary column 'eligibility' where it is always 1 unless the following scenario:
if a user shows a loss, they need to cover that amount in the next month(s) in order to be eligible, so for the first negative month they are 0 until they cover the sum

for instance using a dataset like this:

```
user,month,profit/loss
1,2022-03-01,400
2,2022-03-01,-100
3,2022-03-01,5000
1,2022-04-01,-10
2,2022-04-01,80
3,2022-04-01,400
1,2022-05-01,60
2,2022-05-01,60
```

new column would be

```
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
1
```

Comment: why is the 4rth row (user 1, loss -10) a 0? The user had 400 before the the overall gain is still 390, no?

Comment: Hi I explained it on the post but it might not be as clear. Once a user is negative for a month he is 0 until they recover to a positive sum in the next month or months i.e. once they show a negative month it doesn't matter what their cumsum has been previously

Comment: So if user 1 had -10, then 9, they would remain 0 on both?

Comment: Yes that's correct - also thanks for editing the question to a more readable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'2022-03-01',400],
    [2,'2022-03-01',-100],
    [3,'2022-03-01',5000],
    [1,'2022-04-01',-10],
    [2,'2022-04-01',80],
    [3,'2022-04-01',400],
    [1,'2022-05-01',60],
    [2,'2022-05-01',60]
], columns=['user','month','profit/loss'])

data = (
     pd
    .concat([df.user, df.groupby('user')
    .agg({'profit/loss':'cumsum'})
    .rename(columns={'profit/loss':"cumsum"})], axis=1)
)

data["cummax"] = (
   data
    .groupby('user')
    .agg({'cumsum':'cummax'})
)
data.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['cumsum'] < 0 else 0 if x["cumsum"] < x["cummax"] else 1, axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
dtype: int64
```

instead of apply, you can use `np.where`:

```
pd.Series(np.where(data["cumsum"] < 0, 0, np.where(data["cumsum"] < data["cummax"], 0, 1)))
```

Comment: Hey, this looks good - will check it later on my dataset and mark it as the answer if everything's ok

Comment: @henrycmcjo I think if your data is huge, it is better to use `np.where` as mentioned in last lines of post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could loop through the dataset, and when a loss is found, map that loss to the corresponding user in any desired manner (for example a dictionary or a hashmap) and add a 0 to the column.

When a profit is found, check if that user is currently at a loss, if so, add the profit to the loss, and if the result of the addition is greater than 0, the record can be deleted and a 1 can be added to the column. If the user with the profit is not found to be currently a loss, just move on and add a 1 to the column.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear, so assuming you want 1 when a user has an overall positive (or null) profit, and 0 if negative, you can use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and compare to `0`:

```
df['out'] = df.groupby('user')['profit/loss'].cumsum().gt(0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   user       month  profit/loss  out
0     1  2022-03-01          400    1
1     2  2022-03-01         -100    0
2     3  2022-03-01         5000    1
3     1  2022-04-01          -10    1  # (*) see note below
4     2  2022-04-01           80    0
5     3  2022-04-01          400    1
6     1  2022-05-01           60    1
7     2  2022-05-01           60    1

# (*) this value is different from yours, but the overall gain is 390 (>0)
```

Comment: I think OP means although it is 390 but it is less than 400 that was before and out must be 0 until it will be equal to 400 or greater.

Comment: Then `(df['profit/loss'].gt(0) & df.groupby('user')['profit/loss'].cumsum().gt(0)).astype(int)`

Comment: Hi, I replied above but just for visibility: once a user shows negative for a month they are labelled as 0 and the 'counter' resets i.e. previous months are ignored. To turn to '1' they need to cover the loss, in this case -10, in the coming months. So the solution isn't just to get the cumsum

Comment: hey @mozway just letting you know that `(df['profit/loss'].gt(0) & df.groupby('user')['profit/loss'].cumsum().gt(0)).astype(int)` also gives incorrect results

Comment: @henrycmcjo if you really need to consider a present and future (but not past) cumsum with threshold, then I guess a vectorial solution in not possible, you'll have to loop